# PHP warning : move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php & trying to build a small application.
Below piece is running successfully on a php page, where we don't have any code other than this. when I use the same code on other php form above error "move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move" comes.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    $file=$_FILES['file'];
    //files properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];
    // work out the files extension
    $file_ext = explode('.',$file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));
    $allowed = array('doc','docx','pdf','rtf','txt');
    //print_r($file_ext);
    if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed))
    {
        if($file_error==0)
        {
            if($file_size<=5000000)
            {
                $file_name_new=uniqid('',true).'.'.$file_ext;
                $file_destination = '/./Resume/'.$file_name_new;
                //$_SESSION['message']= $file_tmp; 
                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_destination))
                {
                    echo"file uploaded sucessfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['message']= "File not uploaded to the destination".$file_name;
                }
            }
            else
            {
            $_SESSION['message']= "Files size is more than 5 MB";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['message']= "some unexpected error happened";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message']= "Please upload file matching the below extensions only"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: you should check if the directory exists and whether you have permissions

Comment: as per my comments, same piece of code is very working on other php page under same project but not working in this page. I hope permissions won't change by page. Also directory also exist.

Comment: Please check :  $file_destination = '/./Resume/'.$file_name_new; might be a valid destination for the working php page & not for the other.

Comment: Yes, try using absolute paths and see if problem persists